# htacess https:// not redirecting to https://www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, server, ssl-certificate

Wordpress website. If you load http://example.com or https://example.com you get a security error on mobile. Redirect works fine on PC taking the user to https://www.example.com

What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

Answer (score 1):

A security error likely has nothing to do with your redirects or .htaccess.    It probably means that your website is not serving a valid security certificate for requests for `example.com`.   To be able to redirect from `https://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` you **MUST** secure that redirect with a security certificate for `example.com`.

The usual way do do this is to get a certificate with subject alternative names (SAN) for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`.   Alternately the names could be `example.com` and `*.example.com` (wildcard certificate.)

As for why it is working on desktop for you, there are two possibilities:

- You have a cached 301 redirect
- You clicked through to accept the security certificate at some point